# Matrix from table in blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have

> table called "matrixs", field are (kriteria1, kriteria2, grade)

in my mvc I did this :

> First by calling my model called "matrix" in "AHPController" :

`$alltable = Matrix::all(); return view('result', compact('alltable'));`

> and called it in "result" view :

`@foreach($alltable as $r1)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $r1->kriteria1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $r1->kriteria2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $r1->grade }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach`

> I got this result

[image]

how to echo it in blade so it become like this : [image]

just ignore the color, only need the matrix shown in blade in that format. Thank you.

Comment: How is that information stored when outputted in the first table, in order to convert the data output we need to know how it's structured to being with. Please include the view file in which you create the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do in this case is first build up a 2 dimensional array and then loop over that array in your view.

```php
// In your controller method
$records = Matrix::orderBy('kriteria2')
    ->orderBy('kriteria1')
    ->get();

$rows = [];
$columns = [];
foreach($records as $index => $record) {
    // Create an empty array if the key does not exist yet
    if(!isset($rows[$record->kriteria1])) {
        $rows[$record->kriteria1] = [];
    }

    // Add the column to the array of columns if it's not yet in there
    if(!in_array($record->kriteria2, $columns)) {
        $columns[] = $record->kriteria2;
    }

    // Add the grade to the 2 dimensional array
    $rows[$record->kriteria1][$record->kriteria2] = $record->grade;
}
```

Then in your view you can loop over it like this:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><!-- Empty for the left top corner of the table --></th>
            @foreach($columns as $column)
            <th>{{ $column }}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($rows as $kriteria1 => $columns)
        <tr>
            <td><strong>{{ $kriteria1 }}</strong></td>
            @foreach($columns as $kriteria2 => $grade)
            <td>{{ $grade }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Update for second question in comment below:

```php
// In your controller method
$records = Matrix::orderBy('kriteria2')
    ->orderBy('kriteria1')
    ->get();

// Build up a map like this from the data with the names
$names = [
    'kriteria1' => 'name1',
    'kriteria2' => 'name2',
    'kriteria3' => 'name3',
];

$rows = [];
$columns = [];
foreach($records as $index => $record) {
    $name1 = $names[$record->kriteria1];
    $name2 = $names[$record->kriteria2];

    // Create an empty array if the key does not exist yet
    if(!isset($rows[name1])) {
        $rows[name1] = [];
    }

    // Add the column to the array of columns if it's not yet in there
    if(!in_array(name2, $columns)) {
        $columns[] = name2;
    }

    // Add the grade to the 2 dimensional array
    $rows[name1][name2] = $record->grade;
}
```

Comment: so close, but I still has problem, in my format It has to be matrix type, where each time row and column with same number for example row2(kriteria1) and column2(kriteria2) meet the grade always 1. http://prntscr.com/alvr75 grade should be "5 1 5"

Comment: You can add some sorting while fetching. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I got error FatalErrorException in Ahp.php line 49:
Access to undeclared static property: App\Matrix::$records I use laravel 5.2

Comment: You have typo in answer, it should be $records = Matrix::orderBy('kriteria2'), It's WORKING thanks

Comment: Ahh my mistake there, bad copy/pasting from my editor. :)

Comment: One more question if you dont mind, if I have another table that have kriteria1 and kriteria2 name (actualy kriteria1 and kriteria2 name are same based on value) how to echo it in matrix table so it's not just shown <strong>kriteria1or2_value</strong> instead shown <strong>Kriteria1or2name_basedonid_in_anothertable</strong>.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I'm not quite sure how your data is stored but building up a map like that should not be too hard. Let me know if you need more help. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107716/discussion-between-rikudo-pain-and-roj-vroemen).

Comment: it returns error undefined offset 1, I'm still using your original code. while it has to be return name1, name2, and name3

Comment: I have solved and add it to your previous answer, thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close, you just need to be clever on how you use `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes on the `td` elements.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="{{ count(array_keys($alltable->first()->toArray())) }}">kriteria2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    @foreach(array_keys($alltable->first()->toArray()) as $i => $val)
        <td>{{ $i }}</td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
@foreach($alltable as $i => $r1)
    <tr>
        @if($i == 0)
            <td rowspan="{{ $alltable->count() }}"></td>
        @endif
        <td>{{ $i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $r1->kriteria1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $r1->kriteria2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $r1->grade }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I got weird result like in here http://prntscr.com/alvp6y. It's not viewed as matrix type.